# Application.OnKey for Windows Key

Tags: excel, vba, keyboard-shortcuts, onkeydown

Simple question. I am trying to make my own custom add in and I want to use `Ctrl + WinKey + W` or `Shift + Alt + WinKey + P` but how can I write this so it triggers. For example I know if its `Ctrl + SHift + P` I can use `Application.OnKey "+^p"`

Comment: I don't think `onkey` has an option for this.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.onkey) you can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Storax for putting me on the documentation path. After much deliberation, the outcome is as below:

**WINDOWS USERS:**

This is not currently possible with WinKey. It may be changed in the future. But not yet.

**iOS Users:**

The alternative to WInKey is Cmd, which IS possible. Use `*` to achieve it with `Aplication.OnKey`